# Ansible attempting to Connect to Windows Machine Via SSH (fails)

Tags: windows, ansible

We have a linux ansible server managing software installation on a Windows domain. We have successfully installed software onto all our windows machines without issue. We just added a new Windows 10 computer (yes, we have succesfully connected to other Win10 computers), and when we run our ansible install script we are getting the following error

`fatal: [afc54]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-afc54-22-ansible\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to afc54 [192.168.2.193] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address 192.168.2.193 port 22: Connection timed out\r\nssh: connect to host afc54 port 22: Connection timed out\r\n",
    "unreachable": true`

In the [Gathering Facts] section of the playbook, the new machine shows

`Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setu‌​p.py`

while the other windows machines shows

`Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win‌​_updates.ps1`

Why is ansbile trying to connect via SSH rather than the windows port 5986? The same script works successfully on all our other windows computers, but this one has me stumped.

EDIT:
If I specify the credentials and specs on the machine's line in the host file (i.e. `ansible_user=user@domain ansible_password=password ansible_port=5986 ansible_connection=winrm`) then I get the following error

`afc54 | UNREACHABLE! => { "changed": false, "msg": "kerberos: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579), ssl: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)", "unreachable": true }`

Comment: You don't provide enough information to answer the question. The configuration on your control machines differs (most likely you use a different inventory) and that's why you get different results.

Comment: What more information would be helpful? We have successfully run the script on the exact same make and model of Windows computer, Dell Optiplex 3040, Win10, Powershell V5. I've never seen Ansible try to connect to a Windows computer with SSH, any idea what could cause that?

Comment: I am not clear why this worked, but I changed the group name in the hosts file and in the playbook (it was [install] is now [windows]), and it's now running correctly.

Comment: are you sure the other windows boxes, that you say, work, use ssh? Ansible [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#windows-how-does-it-work) suggest otherwise.

Comment: No, all the other windows boxes use winrm, that's why I was confused as to why ansible was trying to connect to this one with ssh. Although for whatever reason, since I changed the group name, it is now connecting to the new one via winrm.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not clear why this worked, but I changed the group name in the hosts file and in the playbook (it was `[install]` is now `[windows]`), and it's now running correctly.

EDIT: A year later I finally noticed the reason this worked. In the `group_vars` directory, there was nothing set up for `[install]` but there was an existing configuration for `[windows]` under `windows.yml` Hopefully this helps someone else =)